# $f$ is a smooth map $R^n \rightarrow R^n$ such that $f\circ{f}=f$. Proving that $f(R^n)$ is a smooth surface in $R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Given that $f$ is a smooth map $R^n \rightarrow R^n$ such that $f\circ{f}=f$, how can I prove that $f(R^n)$ is a smooth surface in $R^n$?

So, I need to prove that each point of $f(R^n)$ has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to an open subset of $R^k$, $k \leq n$.

All I managed to understand is that $f$ is an identity function on a subset of $R^n$ and sends the complement of that subset to that same subset. Any hints?

Comment: Take a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which is the identity on $[0, 1]$ and has no fix point elsewhere (this is possible to take $f$ smooth). Then, $f(\mathbb R)=[0, 1]$ which is a manifold with boudary, so you are not going to show that it is a manifold without boundary...

Comment: @elidiot You can't make such $f$ satisfy $f\circ f=f$, though, and $f(\mathbb{R})$ will be strictly larger than $[0,1]$ since $f$ is increasing on some nhood of $1$ by smoothness.